# Second-order methods in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm looking to do some experiments for research with second-order methods on deep neural networks. It appears that none of the [optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train) built into TensorFlow are second-order. But there has been a [module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/446) written that allows TensorFlow to interface with external optimizers, such as l-BFGS in SciPy.

Is this how people would generally go about doing such experiments? Or is there a much better way that I'm missing?

Comment: The Optimizer class, parent of the available optimizers, can be a starting point to implement one yourself, with second-order derivatives. Basically, this would rely on Tensorflow’s auto-differentiation facilities. A simpler alternative is to use the `calculate_gradients` and `apply_gradients` twice, for fiddling at first. BTW I remember some discussion; there is no standard optimizer with second-order derivatives for they require too much extra compute for the expected benefits. But they are implementable (no limitation of the framework).

Comment: Note, I have made a mistake on a function name. `tf.gradients` is the right name, not "calculate_gradients". Also, `tf.hessians` is also available from the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizers).

Comment: A last comment: Some people have [working implementations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/446) already.

Comment: @EricPlaton Thanks. I had meant to link to that in my question. Just to be clear, you're saying two options are 1. Create my own child class of `Optimizer' and 2. Use the module allowing you to interface with existing optimizers (e.g. from SciPy)? (#2 is what you linked to, I believe).

Comment: Yes, (1) or (2). As for (1) an alternative is also to use `tf.hessians` and related API directly, for simple trials.